# React Native Splash Screen android build failed

Tags: android, react-native, splash-screen

in android/app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-splash-screen')
}
```

in android/app/src/main/java/com/[projectName]/MainApplication.java

```
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreenReactPackage;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

    private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
            return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
            return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
                    new MainReactPackage(),
            new SplashScreenReactPackage()  //here
            );
        }
    };

    @Override
    public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
        return mReactNativeHost;
    }
}
```

whenever i add these code, the build for android get failed and gives these error.

[image]

i'm using react-native-splash-screen package for the splashscreen in both iOS and android. It works well with iOS, the build failed is only on android.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: not yet. still trying to figure it out. and looking for the solutions

Answer (score 0):

Update android/build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        // Add ===========================
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        // ===============================
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```